# Location of template of popup of Magento

Tags: jquery, magento

I am using **11se**  Package in one of my Magento site. I can see a Popup when I click to *Add to Cart* button. Popup looks like below.

[image]

I would like to know the location of the template of the **Popup**. Could anyone help me in this regard ?? Thanks

Comment: is it possible to provide your site url or url from where you have purchased?

Answer (score 0):

Following things you can do in order to debug this popup -

> - Install **Magento Template Path Hints** Extension (easy way to ON/OFF template path hints)
> - Also you can **enable the template path hints from Administration area**.

After installing this extension you'll able to see the path for each files which is including in a particular page.

One more thing you can do is -

You can use mass file search mechanism (using your editor if it has Mass file search feature). You can search with **"was added to your shopping cart"** keyword as this is the common syntax for all products after adding to cart except product name on popup.

These are the fast technique to debug the things.

Enjoy!!

Comment: I tried using **enable the template path hints from Administration area.** But I this is not working. 

Even I tried with  "was added to your shopping cart" but the find result is empty. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: Try to do mass search from root folder of application. May be it is coming from any local/community module which is being added for Ajax Add to Cart functionality.